# How to delete the entire row in table using PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql

How to add a delete button to make the entire delete in Mysql DB. ?Below is the code and how can i delete the row using ID which is a primary key..

```
<?php 
mysql_connect( 'localhost', 'off', 'off') or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db( 'myDB') or die(mysql_error()); 
$query=mysql_query( "select * from test") or die(mysql_error()); 
echo '<table border="1" ><th>ID</th>
                        <th >First Name</th>
                        <th>Lsat Name</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>Mobile</th>
                        <th>Gender</th>
                        <th>Action</th>'; 
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)) { 
        echo '<tr><td>'.$row[ 'id']. '</td><td>'.$row[ 'firstname']. '</td>
                  <td>'.$row[ 'lastname']. '</td><td>'.$row[ 'email']. '</td>  
                  <td>'.$row[ 'mobile']. '</td><td>'.$row[ 'gender']. '</td>
                  <td><a href="">Delete</a> &emsp;</td></tr>'; } 
echo '</table>';
?>
```

Comment: Please format your code (add new-lines per command)

Comment: You need to use ajax request to send `ID` of row which user want to delete on button click. Its a brief topic

Comment: is possible to do the task by php alone

Answer (score -1, accepted):

link your delete anchor to new page

```
<a href="delete.php?id='.$row[ 'id'].'">Delete</a>
```

and on delete.php

```
if(!empty($_GET['id'])) {
  $id= trim($_GET['id']);
  $query = mysql_query( "delete from test where id= '$id'");
  if($query) {
    // success redirect back to another page
  }
}
```

Comment: This code is vulnerable to SQL INJECTION :(

Answer (score 1):

Your link has to point to your php script with the id attached like this:

```
<a href="update.php?action=delete&id={your_id}">Delete</a>
```

Everything after update.php? are GET-Parameters, search how to use $_GET in PHP and check for the action

Afterwards write a sql command that will delete the entry with the ID you've send via $_GET

Good luck, if you get stuck just edit your question with your aproach.

Answer (score 0):

you could make the href a link to the same page with the id parameter (and a delete paremeter, if you want) passed in, then alter the page so that it checks to see if such a parameter has been passed and if so runs a query to delete that row before continuing and loading the page.